# How to append entry the end of a multi-line entry using any of stream editors like sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, sh

I am trying to use a script to append the host name at the end of a multi-line entry of a specific Host_Alias field in sudoers file.

The current sudoers file has an entry similar to :

```
Host_Alias  srv_linuxestate= \
            host10,host12,host13,host1,host50,\
            host16,host1,host2,host11,host15,host21,\
            host3,host14
```

My required output would be something like the following where I have added **",host25"**

```
Host_Alias  srv_linuxestate= \
            host10,host12,host13,host1,host50,\
            host16,host1,host2,host11,host15,host21,\
            host3,host14,host25
```

There are more lines before and after this segment.

The values for the hosts could change and is not fixed. Also there could be many more lines as above and these being separated using "\" at the end of the incomplete line.

Any help/pointers would be great.

Comment: Whats underneath the last line ?

Comment: The rest of the sudoers file continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `sed` version:

```
/^Host_Alias/{                  # whenever we match Host_Alias at line start
:
/\\$/{N;b}                      # if backslash, append next line and repeat
s/$/,host25/                    # add the new host to end of line
}
```

If you need to add your new host to just one of the host aliases, adjust the first match to suit.  In your example, it should probably be `/^Host_Alias  *srv_linuxestate=/`, or `/^Host_Alias[ \t][ \t]*srv_linuxestate=/` if there might be tabs instead of spaces.

If you need it as a one-liner, that becomes `sed -i -e '/^Host_Alias[ \t][ \t]*srv_linuxestate=/{;:;/\\$/{N;b};s/$/,host25/;}' /etc/sudoers`.

Comment: Thanks Toby. It worked like a charm....Now learning a bit on what the command does as I am not a sed expert :)

Comment: Search the Web for `sed tutorial` and pick the first one that you get on with.  And have fun!

Comment: I am not able to get this to work properly when I try to put this hostname as a variable and using double quotes for sed. When I do so, the first pattern matched like is appended with the ,hostname. Can you help me where I am making the mistake below:

sed -i -e "/^Host_Alias[ \t][ \t]*srv_linuxestate=/{;:;/\\$/{N;b};s/$/,${HOSTNAME}/;}" /etc/sudoers

Comment: I would only put double quotes around the bit with the variable and keep single quotes for the rest of the commend:  `sed -i -e '/^Host_Alias[ \t][ \t]*srv_linuxestate=/{;:;/\\$/{N;b};s/$/,'"${HOSTNAME}/;}"`. Otherwise you end up with bash interfering in sed's domain.  In particular, bash expands that `\\ `, which means that sed will see only `\ ` there.

Comment: Perfect.. Nothing more from me at this moment :)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk with empty record separator:

```
awk -v RS= '$1=="Host_Alias" {$0 = $0 ",host25"} 1' /etc/sudoers
Host_Alias  srv_linuxestate= \
            host10,host12,host13,host1,host50,\
            host16,host1,host2,host11,host15,host21,\
            host3,host14,host25
```

This is assuming there is an empty line after last line of `Host_Alias` as in the regular `sudoers` file.

Comment: How do you know the next line is blank ?

Comment: Hope you saw the comment I added in answer. In my `/etc/sudoers` there are empty lines after each section.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. There are multiple Host_Aliases so I believe I need to modify the search parameter ?

Comment: Yes that's right otherwise this command will add `,host25` after every `Host_Alias ` section.

Comment: I am not able to get the filter right, may be because of the spaces. Can you help me out with that. Mine is having a tab after the Host_Alias before the alias name

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on single lines, that is all. All of the arcane sed constructs to do anything else became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented so just use awk:

```
$ awk '/Host_Alias/{f=1} f && !/\\/{$0=$0",host25"; f=0} {print}' file
Host_Alias  srv_linuxestate= \
            host10,host12,host13,host1,host50,\
            host16,host1,host2,host11,host15,host21,\
            host3,host14,host25
```

The above simply sets a flag when it finds a line containing `Host_Alias` and when that flag is set and the current line doesn't contain `\` it adds `,host25` to the end of the line and clears the flag.

Simple, clear, maintainable, efficient, portable, extensible, etc. etc. - better in every way than an equivalent sed solution.